# Can't access array that's in an Object

Tags: angular

So I have this:

```
<div *ngIf="(foods$ | async)| json as foods"> <pre>{{foods}}<br></pre></div>
```

Which prints out this:

```
{"foods": [
{
  "name": "1",
  "fat": "2"
},
{
  "name": "2",
  "fat": "3"
},
{
  "name": "3",
  "fat": "4"
},
{
  "name": "4",
  "fat": "5"
}
```

]
}

And when I try to do this:

```
<div *ngIf="(foods$ | async)| json as foods"> <pre>{{foods.name}} {{foods.fat}}<br></pre</div>
```

I get this:
TS2339: Property 'name' does not exist on type 'string'.

```
{{foods.name}}{{foods.fat}}
```

Property 'fat' does not exist on type 'string'.

```
{{foods.name}}{{foods.fat}}
```

It's foods$ is an observable and when I remove "| json"
I get [object Object]

what I'm trying to access is .name and .fat, to put it into a table like this:
[image]

Here's what I get in my console log btw:
[image]

So Again, i'm trying to use angular to display my data in a table

Thanks

Comment: Remove the JSON pipe in your html and add null checks on your objects. {{foods?.name}} {{foods?.fat}}

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I got this: error TS2339: Property 'name' does not exist on type 'string'.

3   <pre>{{foods?.name}}<br></pre>

Answer (score 1):

`foods.name` doesn't exist because foods contains an array, not a `name` field. Each element in the array contains a `name` value but to access those names you need to specify which element's name you want. Like this,

```
foods[i].name
```

Where i is the index of the element that you want to select. For instance `foods[0].name` will return the name of the first food in the list.

To list all of the elements in your array you can use an `*ngFor` to iterate over all the elements in the array,

```
<div *ngFor="let food of (foods$ | async)">
  <p>{{ food.name }} : {{ food.fat }}</p>
</div>
```

This will loop over all the elements in `foods` and for each `food` in `foods` it will create a p tag with that food's name and fat values.

To put those values in a table, just replace the p tag with your table row.